# python3のエラー "TypeError: Tensors ... that don't all match" がわからない

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oshikawaakinobu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 458, in _apply_op_helper
    raise TypeError()  # All types should match.
TypeError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_mnist.py", line 235, in <module>
    main(parser.parse_args())
  File "run_mnist.py", line 137, in main
    pred = deep_mnist(args, x, train_phase)
  File "/Users/oshikawaakinobu/mnist_model.py", line 35, in deep_mnist
    cv1 = hn_lite.conv2d(x, nf, fs, padding='SAME', n_rings=nr, name='1')
  File "/Users/oshikawaakinobu/harmonic_network_lite.py", line 38, in conv2d
    name=name)
  File "/Users/oshikawaakinobu/harmonic_network_ops.py", line 56, in h_conv
    new_shape = tf.concat(axis=0, values=[Ysh[:3],[max_order+1,2],[Ysh[3]/(2*(max_order+1))]])
  File "/Users/oshikawaakinobu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1113, in concat
    return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/Users/oshikawaakinobu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1029, in concat_v2
    "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/Users/oshikawaakinobu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 483, in _apply_op_helper
    raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [int32, int32, float32] that don't all match.
```

Comment: スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！実行しているコードを貼り付けたり、何をしようとしていて、何がわからないのかを具体的に書くと答えが得られやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: 実行しようとしているコードはこれだったりしますかね？ https://github.com/deworrall92/harmonicConvolutions

Answer (score 2):

TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [int32, int32, float32] that don't all match　（直訳：　型のエラー　ConcatV2' Op　の値に渡されている list内のテンソルは、[int32, int32, float32]という型を持っている。 (テンソルの値は全部が同じ型でないといけないのに）型が一致していない！
　というのが、エラーの内容です。

listを作っているところで、int32の値とfloat32の値を混用しているのがエラーの原因だ指摘されている訳ですから、そういう視点でコードを見直すと問題の箇所が見つけやすいだろうと思います。

Comment: new_shape = tf.concat(axis=0, values=[Ysh[:3],[max_order+1,2],[Ysh[3]/(2*(max_order+1))]])　こちらの書き方に問題点は有りますか？それとも最後の[Ysh[3]/(2*(max_order+1))]]がfloat型になるのでint型にていせいすればいいですか？

Comment: 型が[int32, int32, int32]であれば、質問に書かれたエラーは出なくなるはずです。何をしていらっしゃるのか知らないので、それで正しい答えが出るかどうかは判りません。